# Sorting a string and returning it

Tags: python

So I have this code where I want sort a string and return it

```
    def sort_int_string(one_string):

        one_string = one_string.replace("\n", ' ')
        one_string = one_string.replace("\t", ' ')
        one_string = one_string.strip()

       if len(one_string) == 0:
            return ''
       else: 
            one_string = one_string.split(" ")
            one_string = [int(i) for i in one_string]
            one_string.sort()
            one_string = [str(i) for i in one_string]
            return ' '.join(one_string)
```

But when I try to run it with this.

```
    hello = "\t42    4    -17\n"
    print(sort_int_string(hello)
```

I get the error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Not sure why I'm getting that. Please help.

Comment: use `one_string.strip().split(" ")`

Comment: `.split(" ")` splits on each individual space - since you have multiple spaces between your numbers, this results in a bunch of empty strings in your list.  `.split()` (with no parameter) splits on runs of spaces (or other whitespace characters), which is what you probably want here.

Comment: Apart from that error message, the traceback contains more useful information that can help us help you. [Edit] your post and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you have empty string present in the array and when a check is made on that it returns an error since it can't be converted to int. So just do a conditional to check that the i value is not an empty string.

```py
def sort_int_string(one_string):

    one_string = one_string.replace("\n", ' ')
    one_string = one_string.replace("\t", ' ')
    one_string = one_string.strip()

    if len(one_string) == 0:
        return ''
    else: 
        one_string = one_string.split(" ")
        one_string =  [int(i) for i in one_string if i != ""]
        one_string.sort()
        one_string = [str(i) for i in one_string]
        return ' '.join(one_string) 

hello = "\t42    4    -17\n"
print(sort_int_string(hello))
```

outputs

`-17 4 42`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because several of the values for `i` are `''` (empty string) and you are trying to cast them to integers. Like the comments above suggest, use `strip` and `split` to remove whitespace. Then sort:

```py
def sort_int_string(one_string):
    return sorted(one_string.strip().split())

hello = "\t42    4    -17\n"
output = sort_int_string(hello)
print(output)  # returns ['-17', '4', '42']
```

If you want to recombine the output back into a string you can use `' '.join(output)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

you don't have to replace `\n` and `\t` with `" "`. `strip()` will remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
def sort_int_string(one_string):
  string_lst = one_string.strip().split(" ")
  string_lst.sort()
  return ''.join(string_lst)

hello = "\t42    4    -17\n"
print(sort_int_string(hello))
```

**output:**
`-17442`

Answer (score 0):

I realized some of the list items after

> one_string = one_string.split(" ")

were empty quotes so I looped through **one_string** to eliminate them by storing it in a new list, after the loop, I overwrote the old list with the new one as shown below

```
def sort_int_string(one_string):

    one_string = one_string.replace("\n", ' ')
    one_string = one_string.replace("\t", ' ')
    one_string = one_string.strip()


    if len(one_string) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        one_string = one_string.split(" ")

        new_one_string = [];

        for num in one_string:
            if num != '':
                new_one_string.append(num)

        one_string = new_one_string;

        one_string = [int(i) for i in one_string]
        one_string.sort()
        one_string = [str(i) for i in one_string]

        return ' '.join(one_string)
```

The output:

**-17 4 42**